# Recursively update dataframe structure in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

My code reads a bunch of csv files and for each of them I want to update the structure with a new dataframe.

I could do that in Matlab easily but i don't know how to do that with Python. 
 My code looks like this:

```
            for filename in filenames:
            if filename.__contains__("Mycsv") == 1:
                df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', header=None)
```

How to put all this df in one structure?

Comment: Maybe post your matlab solution to illustrate what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of datafranes:

```
df_list=[]
for filename in filenames:
    if filename.__contains__("Mycsv") == 1:
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', header=None))
```

Then merge the read dataframes (assuming same columns):

```
df_final=pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

Comment: yes this one is what I was after, without concat part.

i want to keep them in that order so i can index each array.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what structure you want to put it in. You can do it pretty elegantly with list or dictionary comprehensions.

For a list:

```
answer = [ pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', header=None)            
                   for filename in filenames 
                   if 'Mycsv' in filenames
                 ]
```

You can index into this like answers[0].

For a dictionary:

```
answer = dict((filename, pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', header=None))             
                   for filename in filenames 
                   if 'Mycsv' in filenames
                  )
```

You can index this like answers[filename].

Comment: This one appends the new data to the existing dataframe.
I want to achieve a Structure with different arrays inside. 
Each matrix array created from each csv file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Can you give an example result?